# Aw, Snap Error in Chrome for Jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am getting below error only on chrome browser

Aw, Snap!

Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.Closing the apps and tabs that you don't need may help by making more memory avilable

Below is Jquery code which gets data from database and add to options

```js
$.post('getCustomerName.htm',
  {
   custTypeId :  ""+$('#custTypeId').val(),channelId :  ""+channelId,regionId : ""+$('#regionId').val()
  },
  function(data) {
   $("#searchProgress").hide();
   var options='<option value="X">--Select--</option>';
   var option2='<option value="X">--Select--</option>';
         if(data != null)
         {
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     options += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '" id="' +data[i].customerName +'">' + data[i].customerName + ' </option>';
     option2 += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '" id="' +data[i].previousMasterRecordNumber +'">' + data[i].previousMasterRecordNumber + ' </option>';

    }
         }
   $("select#customerName").html(options);
    $("select#dcode").html(option2);
   
  });
```

This error only occurs in chrome browser is there any solutions.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle or similar demonstrating the problem?

Comment: How many elements does your `data`-object contain?

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g94a79nb/) - here it works on chrome.

Comment: Nearly 40000 data elements are there

Comment: Jordumus is it due to excess data elements

Comment: Are you sure you're not just running out of memory on your device? Also: be aware that 40 000 elements is -a lot- to manipulate. My jsFiddle from above does crash as well when I change the number from 50 to 40 000

Comment: No , I checked it doesn't go out of memory. Same if I run through any other browser ex FireFox it displays the output. Only problem in chrome

Comment: Its Client requirement.

Comment: I'm afraid that the amount of elements is your problem here. You'll have to find a way to filter out those, or to load them bit by bit instead of in 1 huge batch.

Comment: Its already filtered using type of customer. This lists all customer of x type under that channel. This is requirement and at the same time it runs on other browser.